# Teradata Mload Error : UTY4014 Access module error '42' received during 'get position' operation

Tags: file, module, teradata, mload

I hope some one can help me with the following problem. While loading a file through MLoad I am getting the below error *'Unable to obtain data signature Quoted data- Column missing close quote !ERROR! No corresponding close quote for open quote was found. OpenQuoteOffset=456 BufferSize=65536 BufferPosition=238'*.

Want to know how to identify the row number in the file for which I am facing the issue.

```
     ========================================================================
     =                                                                      =
     =          MultiLoad Acquisition Phase                                 =
     =                                                                      =
     ========================================================================
**** 09:40:42 UTY1818 As requested, no record checkpoints will be performed for
     this task.
**** 09:40:42 UTY0817 MultiLoad submitting the following request:
     BEGIN TRANSACTION;
**** 09:40:42 UTY0817 MultiLoad submitting the following request:
     CHECKPOINT LOADING INTERVAL 0;
**** 09:40:42 UTY0817 MultiLoad submitting the following request:
     CHECKPOINT LOADING INTERVAL 0;
**** 09:40:43 UTY4014 Access module error '42' received during 'get position'
     operation: 'Unable to obtain data signature Quoted data- Column missing
     close quote !ERROR! No corresponding close quote for open quote was found.
     OpenQuoteOffset=456 BufferSize=65536 BufferPosition=238'
**** 09:40:43 UTY1821 Aquisition Phase statistics
     Elapsed time:  00:00:01
     CPU time:      0 Seconds
     MB/sec:        0
     MB/cpusec:     N/A
```

Comment: How much data do you have? It is possible that your data is defined to have quotes around fields but data itself contains quotes (maybe in some free text field).
Try this regex `[^,]"[^,]`to find the bad record. Notepad++ or `grep` can help you with regex. Replace comma with your delimiter and possibly the double quote mark with single quote based on your file schema

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The problem is solved now. It was because of a special character Carriage Return in the data file. After removing it load went successfully.